# How to locally serve static website which has human readable urls | How to rewrite urls in a dev server?

Tags: url-rewriting, webserver, folder-structure

So let's say there are static files

```
- index.html ( / )
- blog
-- index.html ( /blog )
-- blog-post.html ( /blog/blog-post )
```

Question 1: are this urls human readable?

Question 2: when people use ssg or create static website some other way do they make such urls?

Question 3: if they do, what server they use during development to serve such folder structure with such url structure?

Question 4: is it possible to serve website using something like live-server but change urls with something like nginx to get best of both?

What I want Ideally:

1. server that can serve files with that url and folder structure
2. simple cli interface like I "cd" to a folder which I want to serve, call "server" possibly with some arguments (maybe tell it where config file is located), and when I am done I just stop it with ctrl-c.
3. live reload (change in say css file or js file is reflected on a page served. For example like https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server)

Apparently this folder/url structure requires url rewrites.

Most programs don't have rewrite rules, others that do have them like apache or nginx don't look like a good solution for a dev server (am I wrong?)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server

Has rewrites but I don't see how to make them work when I have both blog-post.html and index.html look as same url structure like /some-file

I can replace it like this

```
- index.html ( / )
- blog.html ( /blog )
- blog
-- blog-post.html ( /blog-post )
```

But how to replace the first index.html at /

Why I think apache or nginx isn't good:

1. requires root privileges
2. it is a service and I don't know how they work and how to configure them
3. uses config files, instead of simply cd to folder that I want to serve I have to edit config file again with root privilege each time

Why the need to configure?

- by default it starts serving as soon as I log in, this is not what I want, I want to start it only when I want.

With nginx I was able to get it to serve files with:

```
server {
    listen       8080;

    location / {
        root /my-folder;
        index  index.html;
        # kill cache
        expires -1;

        # works but also serves with a trailing slash
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html $uri/ =404;
        # redirect trailing slash
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
        # redirect index.html
        rewrite ^/(.*)/index.html$ /$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

Idk if it is done correctly but it works.

Still it is not exactly what I want.

Comment: I'm not familiar with npmjs, but most web servers have the concept of "directory index" files. You usually don't need to do anything to have `/` served by `index.html`, that is usually the default handled by the directory index configuration.   Hopefully somebody here knows if npmjs supports this and if so what the configuration would be.

Comment: It doesn't have to be npm or js based, it's just local-web-server is easy to use in command line and kind of has rewrites but its either can't do what I want or I don't understand how to use it, I am able to make it serve index files or non index files but I can't make it work with both.

Comment: You might do better just running Apache or Nginx locally.

Comment: Can I do that with a command? I need to change folders being served often.

Comment: You say "no way to tell that /blog is actually an index of a folder".  Do you really mean to say "no way to tell that /blog is actually an index.html OR a folder"?

Comment: I say it because in local-web-server you can write rewrite rules like client request /blog-post and server serves /blog-post.html, so it's like you have "from" and "to". How do I tell now inside "from" which url is an index and which is not when their shape is identical?

Comment: For example by default local-web-server can serve "blog/index.html" when I request "/blog".

Next I try to make non-index files to be served with something like:
`ws --rewrite '/([a-z-/]*) -> $1.html'`
(I actually need more complicated stuff than [a-z-/] but for testing it will do.)

After this I can see files  /blog/blog-post.html but I cannot see /blog/index.html

Comment: If index and non index files would have different url shapes I could write a regexp to capture one or the other but not both. But I think user shouldn't know or care what is a folder index and what is a file.

Comment: It is probably possible to hardcode all the urls but this is terrible. And the problem seems so simple and was probably solved many times. Modern ssg should have some kind of dev server and probably use human readable urls right?

Comment: I think you are wrong about Apache (or nginx) not being a good solution for a dev server.  I'd argue that "LAMP" and "WAMP" as in Linux/Windows **Apache** MySQL PHP - stacks are pretty standard for many developers.   I note that what you are trying to do is fairly easy with Apache rewrite rules.   I know of a business that tried to use Zop - which has its own Python based webserver - it was a disaster for them.  I wonder to what extent npmjs is a similar folly.  If you absolutely need to run npmjs you can always put it behind an apache reverse proxy....

Comment: I don't need mysql or php or node, the website is static. Does apache have a cli interface so that I could run it only when I wan't by calling `apache` instead of starting and stopping service.